# Windows 8 remote db access without WCF

Tags: mysql, windows-8

Is there any way to directly access a mysql DB in a windows 8 app, i.e. without WCF Service or need to deploy in App store?

Answer (score 0):

No.  You either need to use WCF, or access your database via a webserver from within your app.

If you really don't want to deploy to the App store, you should build a mobile web app, and not a native app.